# Mat Datepicker min date validation not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-datepicker

I have used mat-datepicker with reactive forms & facing an issue when I tried to set the datepicker's value dynamically.

I have reproduced the issue in the below URL,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxqsdy-7bfebs?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.ts

Kindly check & let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am able to see. Min Datepicker is working as expected. What is the problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to do in the esaExpireDate `[min]="form.get('serializedDate').value"`?